# multipart/form-data - manually get the file information

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out how to find the size of the file I uploaded to my node application.

Purpose of this question is only to expand my knowledge. There is no actual problem, just the need to do something on my own.

My working setup:

I send an file (image). It is encoded as multipart/form-data. In my node controller, I use [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) library that work great. I use it like this (sample not working code):

```
let form = new multiparty.Form(); 

form.on('part', function (part) {    
   //part contains the size of the file that is being sent.
});   

form.parse(request);
```

**Part** object contains all information about the upload. The way I understand it, multiparty library took the information from the header, and parsed it for me.

My question is, how can I manually do it, without using any other library? Just work on the raw request object and its headers.

For starters, at least get the file size. And if I am willing (or have time) get other values from the file.

My question might sound simple, but could be that it is not:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed arguments:

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('received upload:\n\n');
  res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
});
```

I believe, files array - each will have file info you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I did not. You are  sending a callback, which according to the multiparty documentation is used for other things, which I do not use. Also, I do not have a file's array in my complete request object.